# How to get the average of values corresponding to another column in Excel

Tags: excel, average, vlookup

I have a set of excel data as follows;

```
A   B        C      D   E

0   0   0.510678961 3   1
0   1   0.582611161 15  1
0   2   0.274447714 2   1
0   3   0.258144341 2   1
0   4   0.574404811 11  1
0   5   0.330260801 2   1
0   6   0.252972823 2   1
0   7   0.536704433 2   1
0   8   0.563287425 2   1
0   9   0.469793466 32  1
0   10  0.504253272 5   1
0   11  0.509408549 36  4
0   12  0.539940366 54  1
0   13  0.472334971 6   1
0   14  0.423524875 2   1
0   15  0.254872928 13  1
0   16  0.231080412 8   1
0   17  0.39818992  22  1
0   18  0.545173384 4   1
0   19  0.280489713 9   1
0   20  0.280509697 6   1
0   21  0.560193886 6   1
0   22  0.485332134 8   2
0   23  0.481483179 3   1
0   24  0.496115634 29  4
0   25  0.466198213 2   1
0   26  0.552777113 5   1
0   27  0.240848653 6   1
0   28  0.30456948  17  2
0   29  0.315246183 6   1
1   0   0.510678961 3   1
1   1   0.254872928 15  1
1   2   0.274447714 2   1
1   3   0.258144341 40  1
1   4   0.231080412 11  1
1   5   0.330260801 2   1
1   6   0.252972823 2   1
1   7   0.536704433 2   1
1   8   0.563287425 2   1
1   9   0.469793466 32  1
1   10  0.504253272 5   1
1   11  0.509408549 36  4
1   12  0.539940366 54  1
1   13  0.472334971 6   1
1   14  0.423524875 2   1
1   15  0.254872928 13  1
1   16  0.231080412 8   1
1   17  0.39818992  22  1
1   18  0.545173384 4   1
1   19  0.280489713 9   1
1   20  0.280509697 6   1
1   21  0.560193886 6   1
1   22  0.485332134 8   2
1   23  0.481483179 3   1
1   24  0.496115634 29  4
1   25  0.466198213 2   1
1   26  0.552777113 5   1
1   27  0.240848653 6   1
1   28  0.30456948  17  2
1   29  0.315246183 6   1
2   0   0.510678961 3   1
2   1   0.254872928 15  1
2   2   0.274447714 2   1
2   3   0.258144341 40  1
2   4   0.231080412 11  1
2   5   0.330260801 2   1
2   6   0.252972823 2   1
2   7   0.536704433 2   1
2   8   0.386891594 2   1
2   9   0.469793466 32  1
2   10  0.504253272 5   1
2   11  0.509408549 5   1
2   12  0.539940366 54  1
2   13  0.472334971 6   1
2   14  0.423524875 2   1
2   15  0.254872928 13  1
2   16  0.231080412 8   1
2   17  0.39818992  22  1
2   18  0.545173384 4   1
2   19  0.280489713 9   1
2   20  0.280509697 6   1
2   21  0.231080412 6   1
2   22  0.485332134 8   2
2   23  0.481483179 3   1
2   24  0.496115634 29  4
2   25  0.466198213 2   1
2   26  0.552777113 5   1
2   27  0.240848653 6   1
2   28  0.30456948  5   2
2   29  0.315246183 6   1
3   0   0.510678961 3   1
3   1   0.254872928 15  1
3   2   0.274447714 2   1
3   3   0.258144341 40  1
3   4   0.231080412 11  1
3   5   0.330260801 2   1
3   6   0.252972823 2   1
3   7   0.536704433 2   1
3   8   0.386891594 2   1
3   9   0.469793466 32  1
3   10  0.504253272 5   1
3   11  0.509408549 17  1
3   12  0.539940366 54  1
3   13  0.472334971 6   1
3   14  0.423524875 2   1
3   15  0.254872928 13  1
3   16  0.231080412 76  1
3   17  0.39818992  22  1
3   18  0.231080412 4   1
3   19  0.280489713 9   1
3   20  0.280509697 6   1
3   21  0.231080412 6   1
3   22  0.485332134 8   2
3   23  0.481483179 3   1
3   24  0.496115634 29  4
3   25  0.466198213 2   1
3   26  0.231080412 5   1
3   27  0.240848653 6   1
3   28  0.30456948  5   2
3   29  0.315246183 6   1
```

.................................

I need to find the smallest 10 numbers from column C for each set of 30 values and get the corresponding value of them from column D and find the average of those 10 values from column D. This has to be repeated for each set of 30 rows upto 100 sets.

I have tried VLOOKUP with SMALL. But my requirement seem to be too complex that I cannot get the correct answer. I would highly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be asking for to many levels of cyclic calculation. Use helper columns or run the calculations in a vba variant array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `G2` contains the desired group number (from your ColumnA), then the following formula should work:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(colD,colA,G2,colC,"<="&AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((colA=G2)*colC)),10))
```

The `AGGREGATE` function will return the tenth smallest value from an array of the values that are in the appropriate group and `DIV/0` errors if they are not.. the `1/(1/(...` produces the error values (ignored by `AGGREGATE`) in that array.

Given your posted data, I get the following results:

[image]

Note: If there are duplicates in the smallest 10 values in each group, you will be averaging more than 10 values.  Think about exactly what you want to have happen if there are duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for for this answer. Exactly what I was looking for. +1 for pointing out the fact about duplicates. I think averaging all values if duplicates are present suits my requirement. Thanks again for this

Answer (score 1):

Ok this was quite tricky but I think this can be done with simple formulas:

Add to cell *F1*:

`=IF($B1=0,SMALL(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CONCAT("$C",ROW()-MOD(ROW(),30)+1),TRUE),0,0,30),$B1+1),IF($B1<10,SMALL(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CONCAT("$C",ROW()-MOD(ROW(),30)+1),TRUE),0,0,30),$B1+1),""))`

Add to cell *G1*:

`=IF($F1<>"",VLOOKUP($F1,OFFSET(INDIRECT(CONCAT("$C",ROW()-MOD(ROW(),30)+1),TRUE),0,0,30,2),2,FALSE),"")`

Add to cell *H1*:

`=IF(B1=0,AVERAGE($G1:$G10),"")`

And if you fill down your entire sheet it should do what you're looking for. For example range 1:30 will look like this...

```
A   B   C           D   E   F           G   H
0   0   0.510678961 3   1   0.231080412 8   7.1
0   1   0.582611161 15  1   0.240848653 6   
0   2   0.274447714 2   1   0.252972823 2   
0   3   0.258144341 2   1   0.254872928 13  
0   4   0.574404811 11  1   0.258144341 2   
0   5   0.330260801 2   1   0.274447714 2   
0   6   0.252972823 2   1   0.280489713 9   
0   7   0.536704433 2   1   0.280509697 6   
0   8   0.563287425 2   1   0.30456948  17  
0   9   0.469793466 32  1   0.315246183 6   
0   10  0.504253272 5   1           
0   11  0.509408549 36  4           
0   12  0.539940366 54  1           
// The latter 20 rows of each set of 30 will be blank in the computed column...
```

Hope this helps, I'm happy to explain how this works if you like

Comment: I came to the same result using RANK and AVERAGEIFS.